# Dealing with an array in an array?

Tags: php

**UPDATE 1:**

I also have the following `foreach` loop in my code:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){ 
    $message .= $key . " = " .$value ."\n\n<br />"; 
}
```

Which is the final one.

Or maybe the problem is in the line:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
```

Doesn't like the `%5B0%5D` in the string generated, i.e.

```
transaction%5B0%5D=USD+21.00
```

using the code `$req = http_build_query($_POST);`?

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I'm getting the following error message:

```
[Sun Aug 04 10:00:00 2012] [error] [client 000.0.00.000] PHP Warning:  stripslashes() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/page.php on line 20
[Sun Aug 04 10:00:00 2012] [error] [client 000.0.00.000] PHP Stack trace:
[Sun Aug 04 10:00:00 20122] [error] [client 000.0.00.000] PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/page.php:0
[Sun Aug 04 10:00:00 2012] [error] [client 000.0.00.000] PHP   2. stripslashes() /var/www/page.php:20
```

The problem code is this:

```
Line 19: foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
Line 20:     $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
Line 21:     $req .= "&$key=$value";
Line 22: }
```

Where `$_POST` contains the following:

```
Array
(
    [transaction] => Array
        (
            [0] => USD 21.00
        )

    [payment_request_date] => Sat Aug 04 10:00:00 PDT 2012
    [return_url] => http://000.000.000.000/success.php
    [fees_payer] => EACHRECEIVER
    [ipn_notification_url] => http://000.000.000.000/ipn.php
    [sender_email] => buyer_0394820394_per@gmail.com
    [verify_sign] => slkdfj30r2489urj0947830ru0ty80ur0er037jfgoiru932e.as329e
    [test_ipn] => 1
    [cancel_url] => http://000.000.000.000/cancel.php
    [pay_key] => AP-SLKJ30F9J90J3RSD3
    [action_type] => PAY
    [transaction_type] => Adaptive Payment PAY
    [tracking_id] => E4902RJF2
    [status] => COMPLETED
    [log_default_shipping_address_in_transaction] => false
    [charset] => windows-1252
    [notify_version] => UNVERSIONED
    [reverse_all_parallel_payments_on_error] => false
)
```

Is the `stripslashes()` giving me a problem because of the array within an array?  If yes, how can I deal with the `$_POST` in the `foreeach` loop, if no, what could the problem be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the function [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php), which will generate a URL-encoded query string for you.

```
$query_str = http_build_query($_POST);
```

Comment: So replace the whole `foreach` loop with that single line?

Comment: @oshirowanen You should try it first and see what do you get.

Comment: I'm no longer getting an error message, but the code is still not working.  I'm suspecting it may be the next foreach loop which I have just added to the original question.

Comment: I've added further details to `update 1` in the original question.

Comment: @oshirowanen So what is your problem, by the way, you could also using an array for setting post fields for curl.

Answer (score 0):

```
function stripslashes_every_string($array){
  foreach($array as $key => $value){
    $array[$key] = is_array($value) ? stripslashes_every_string($value) : stripslashes($value);
  }
  return $array;
}
$postdata = stripslashes_every_string($_POST);
```

Comment: Will this work for both of my `foreach` loops as shown in my updated question?

Comment: I've added further details to `update 1` in the original question.

Comment: instead of your original foreach, just set a variable to this function passing $_POST in the argument and it should stripslashes of every string. You may need to customize it depending on which functions you want.